# php curl загрузка файла в request payload

Tags: php, api, curl

Подскажите, как передать файл в request payload.
Делаю, так сказать api, для чужого сайта. Нужно, чтобы по быстрому выполнять определенные задачи.

1. Отслеживаю запрос в хром инспекторе
2. Выбираю фотку и нажимаю
   кнопку "Загрузить".
3. В запросах появляется файл upload.php

Мониторю весь запрос, и выясняю. Что файл, каким-то методом передается просто в request payload.
В виде иероглифов и тд.
Я как понял, сам этот request payload - это "body" пост запроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Справа снизу. И как мне, через curl отправить подобный запрос?
Пробовал `curl_file_create(__DIR__.'\1.jpg', 'image/jpeg');`
Не помогает, функция возвращает массив типо
`object(CURLFile)#1 (3) { ["name"]=> string(43) "H:\xampp\htdocs\core\scr\media\1.jpg" ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["postname"]=> string(0) "" }`

Что это за иероглифы и как картинку конвертировать в это? (Наврятли, что там тупо читается файл как текстовый)

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы называете "иероглифами" и есть бинарное представление картинки, просто отображаются только читаемые символы. И там явно видно, что это jpeg.

скорее всего Вам нужны такие параметры для curl

вначале уточним, что посылаем JPEG картинку (такое же и по скриншоту)

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));
```

а также укажем файл, который хочется отправить

```
$params = array('name'=>'@D:\myfile.jpg;type=image/jpeg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

Второй способ найти ответ. В хроме на вкладке networks можно кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши по запросу и там найти "скопировать как курл запрос. А потом воспользоваться любым сервисом вида https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ и получить готовый (или почти готовый) код к использованию.

Comment: Про второй способ знал) Не сработало. А почему, когда я копирую curl запрос в гугл хроме, и пытаюсь повторить его, через какой-нибудь curl online сервис. Мне выдается пустая страница. Т.е. запрос работает через браузер. Но через curl выдается пустая страница

Comment: надо смотреть внимательно. Возможно, запрос так сделан, что он может отработать только один раз, а повторные запросы обрабатываются по другому. Если это загрузка картинки - то это вполне ожидаемое. Кстати, курл имеет опцию `--libcurl имя_файла.с` и он сам сгенерирует исходник на си по командной строке.